# afterClose subscribe not working in mat dialog tests

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to write a test that involves knowing when a  has closed. In my component class I am doing this

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((data) => {
   // do something with data
});
```

And that observable occurs as soon as the dialog is closed. But when I do it in my spec file for my test, it never gets called.

This is what is in my test

```
const dialogRef = dialog.open(CustomDialogComponent, {
  data: {
    title: 'Remove File',
    message: 'Are you sure you want to remove the file?',
  }
});

fixture.detectChanges();

dialogRef.close();

fixture.detectChanges();

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('DIALOG HAS CLOSED');
});
```

And I am getting `dialog` from this `beforeEach()`

```
  beforeEach(inject([MatDialog],
    (d: MatDialog) => {
      dialog = d;
    }));
```

If anyone could help that'd be great. I've been stuck on this for a long time now and don't seem to be getting anywhere.